# How to remove duplicate rows in dataframe In pandas depending upon certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I want to delete duplicate rows only when the status is "completed". 
for the rest of the status like Assigned/In progress/Pending have to keep duplicates rows.

```
            Incident     Status Priority ASGRP Submit Date Completed Date
    Index                                                                
    1       INC001     Assigned      Low    L1  2020-06-01            NaT
    2       INC001  In progress      Low    L2  2020-06-01            NaT
    3       INC001    completed      Low    L1  2020-06-01     2020-06-03
    4       INC001    completed      Low    L1  2020-06-01     2020-06-03
    5       INC001    completed      Low    L1  2020-06-01     2020-06-03
    6       INC002    completed   Medium    L2  2020-06-04     2020-06-04
    7       INC002  In progress   Medium    L1  2020-06-04            Nat
    8       INC002    completed   Medium    L2  2020-06-01     2020-06-01
    9       INC002      Pending   Medium    L2  2020-06-04            NaT
```

the expected output should be like below,

```
           Incident       Status Priority ASGRP Submit Date Completed Date
    Index
    1       INC001     Assigned      Low    L1  2020-06-01            NaT
    2       INC001  In progress      Low    L2  2020-06-01            NaT
    3       INC001    completed      Low    L1  2020-06-01     2020-06-03
    4       INC002  In progress   Medium    L1  2020-06-04            Nat
    5       INC002    completed   Medium    L2  2020-06-01     2020-06-01
    6       INC002      Pending   Medium    L2  2020-06-04            NaT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach:

First get the completed rows without duplicates:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Status'] == 'completed'].sort_values('Incident', ascending=True).drop_duplicates(['Incident'], keep='last')
```

Get the rest of the rows with other Status:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Status'] != 'completed']
```

Result of the two:

```
result = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=False).sort_index()
```

Maybe there are some details that are not usefull like ignoreindex in the last line but... hope it's useful for you.

Comment: thanks, A lot Nand0san, your solution has answered my query :)